# How to generate X509 cert that's acceptable to X509EncodedKeySpec's constructor?

Tags: java, android, rsa, x509

I'm attempting to use OpenSSL to generate a cert that I can ultimately use to instantiate a new X509EncodedKeySpec without having it blow up with InvalidKeySpecException.

So far, I've tried the following:

created the keypair using OpenSSL:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout privkey.pem cert.pem -days 365
```

then in my Android app's encryption class:

```
/** @param rawCert is the content of cert.pem, read into a String. */
public static PublicKey regenerateKey(String rawCert) 
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    byte[] certBytes = Base64.decode(rawCert, 0));
    return kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(certBytes));
}
```

The cert itself looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGDTCCA/WgAwIBAgIJANIT8Fk2cT0HMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGcMQswCQYD
(... removed to save space in posting ...)
Fk7oUsABk7xlpP7kS5+lKfLk+/6DvwIyjU8PB6faBe8EDgXSZMh9K/36Onpvr62i
ysBiCKTT+y+NC3u4cFiTjR4=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

For what it's worth, I already tried the following experiments:

- Read the original .pem file into a String (BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE and all), then converted it into byte[] with the String's getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) method. Failed.
- Same experiment, but tried US_ASCII and ISO_8859_1 instead. Still failed.
- Removed the first and last lines (so the file contained only the base64-encoded cert content). Failed.
- Double-checked to make sure that the .pem file didn't end with a newline. Failed.
- base64-decoded the file to byte[] instead of earlier attempts to use the base64-encoded file. Failed.

The specific relevant line from the stack trace appears to be:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0890ba:ASN.1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:WRONG_TAG

At this point, I'm not sure whether the problem is with the cert itself, or if there's something else (or instead) I need to do to massage it into a form that's acceptable to X509EncodedKeySpec.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. A certificate isn't a public key. It *contains* a public key. You need to generate the certificate itself, and you can get the public key directly from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method. As points @EJP the certificate contains a public key

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(inputStream);
PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
```

`generateCertificate()` accepts a certificate in PEM format (base64 with header and footer) and binary (removing header/footer and decoding the base64 content)

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertificate(java.io.InputStream))

> In the case of a certificate factory for X.509 certificates, the certificate provided in inStream must be DER-encoded and may be supplied in binary or printable (Base64) encoding. If the certificate is provided in Base64 encoding, it must be bounded at the beginning by -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----, and must be bounded at the end by -----END CERTIFICATE-----.